# How can I sort a javascript array of objects numerically and then alphabetically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, sorting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sorting objects in an array by a field value in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129216/sorting-objects-in-an-array-by-a-field-value-in-javascript)

How can I sort an array of objects numerically (by id) then alphabetically (by name)?

The current way is providing invalid output.

This is the object i'm trying to sort through

```
var items = [
    {
        "id": 165,
        "name": "a"
    },
    {
        "id": 236,
        "name": "c"
    },
    {
        "id": 376,
        "name": "b"
    },
    {
        "id": 253,
        "name": "f"
    },
    {
        "id": 235,
        "name": "e"
    },
    {
        "id": 24,
        "name": "d"
    },
    {
        "id": 26,
        "name": "d"
    }
]
```

and the way i'm trying to sort

```
items.sort(function(a, b) {
    return (a.id - b.id);
}).sort(function(a, b) {
    return (a.name - b.name);
});
```

here is the jsfiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/jh4xb/

EDIT: Sorry for the confusion, I've been so confused by this problem for a while.

What I'm trying to accomplish is to sort by the highest id first, and then sort alphabetically so in the end it should look like:

```
var items = [
    {
        "id": 376,
        "name": "b"
    },
    {
        "id": 253,
        "name": "f"
    },
    {
        "id": 236,
        "name": "c"
    },
    {
        "id": 235,
        "name": "e"
    },
    {
        "id": 165,
        "name": "a"
    },
    {
        "id": 26,
        "name": "d"
    },
    {
        "id": 24,
        "name": "d"
    }
]
```

Comment: You might need a better example of what you are trying to accomplish because in this example, sorting by `id` first doesn't make sense since all of the `id`s and `name`s are unique. It's equivalent to just sort by `name`.

Comment: Agreed - what exactly do you want the ordering semantics to be here?

Comment: Not sure what you're hoping to achieve by sorting the list twice. And when you do `return (a.name - b.name)` you're attempting to subtract one string from another. Ain't gonna happen. (You probably want [localeCompare](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/string_localecompare.htm) instead.)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129216/sort-array-of-objects-by-string-property-value-in-javascript/50600956#50600956

Comment: The title of the question is very search friendly. The example is flipped compared to what the title says.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

I think it's better done just with...

```
items.sort(function(a, b) { 
  return a.id - b.id  ||  a.name.localeCompare(b.name);
});
```

The second sort will basically negate the first one, so you have to do it once. )

`a.id - b.id  ||  a.name.localeCompare(b.name)` expression will first compare the `id`s; only if they are equal, it will compare the names (and return the result of this comparison).

If you need to reverse the ordering, swap the positions (`b.id - a.id`, etc.) - or just negate the whole thing:

```
items.sort(function(a, b) { 
  return - ( a.id - b.id  ||  a.name.localeCompare(b.name) );
});
```

Here's the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FCZUV/) (have to simplify the data a bit to show my point).

Comment: Just what I needed! Sorry I wasn't so clear but this is perfect! Thanks!

Comment: Very nice! Thank you for this solution @raina77ow

Answer (score 7):

Create a general function to sort it anyway you want. Check the dynamicSort function below

```
var items = [
{
 "id": 165,
 "name": "a"},
{
 "id": 236,
 "name": "b"},
{
 "id": 376,
 "name": "c"},
{
 "id": 253,
 "name": "d"},
{
 "id": 235,
 "name": "e"},
{
  "id": 24,
  "name": "f"}
];

function dynamicSort(property) {
   return function(a, b) {
       return (a[property] < b[property]) ? -1 : (a[property] > b[property]) ? 1 : 0;
   }
}

items.sort(dynamicSort('name')).sort(dynamicSort('id'));
console.log(items);
items.sort(dynamicSort('id')).sort(dynamicSort('name')); 
console.log(items);
```

Answer (score 5):

IF you mean that you wanted them sorted by `id` and if the `id` matches, you want them sorted by `name` then use this:

```
items.sort(function(a, b) {
    if (a.id !== b.id) {
        return a.id - b.id
    }
    if (a.name === b.name) {
      return 0;
    }
    return a.name > b.name ? 1 : -1;
});
```

Otherwise your question is unclear.

Answer (score 3):

your problem is how you're sorting the letters.
`a.name - b.name`

isn't doing what you think. It's not evaluating them in lexigraphical order.
replace it with

`a.name < b.name ? -1 : 1;`

Comment: Why does your code return `1` if the names are equal? It should return `0`

Comment: you're right. Doing it this way does not guarantee that equal elements will retain their original ordering.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not seeing any errors in Chrome, but it's not sorting correctly.

If I change your sort code to this:

```
var firstRun = items.sort(function(a, b) {
    return (a.id - b.id);
});
var secondRun = firstRun.sort(function(a, b) {
    return (a.name - b.name);
});

console.log(secondRun);​
```

I believe it's sorting correctly.  Your example doesn't really need to do the second sort as each number (id) is different.  But when I make b, d and e all have an ID of 235, it sorts fine.