# Sort by values but alphabetical order when values are same in Javascript

Tags: javascript, loops, object

If I have the object,

```js
const obj = { Peter: 3, Jeremy: 2, Chris: 1, Adam: 2 };
```

I want to compare object values, and sort them in a numerical order.

Therefore, I tried

```js
let answer = Object.keys(obj);

answer.sort((a,b) => {
  return obj[b] - obj[a];
})
```

The output is `['Peter', 'Jeremy', 'Adam', 'Chris']`.

I want to sort `Jeremy` and `Adam` in Alphabetical order as they have same values.

The output I want is `['Peter',  'Adam', 'Jeremy', 'Chris']`

How do I approach to this answer?

Comment: `if (values are the same) { <compare keys> } else { <compare values> }` -> [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: This is essentially the logic you're after [How can I sort a javascript array of objects numerically and then alphabetically?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12900176) so `(a,b) => obj[b] - obj[a] || a.localeCompare(b)` would be your compare function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use a condition for case where values are same to sort based on alphabetical order of keys

```js
const obj = { Peter: 3, Jeremy: 2, Chris: 1, Adam: 2 };

let answer = Object.keys(obj);

answer.sort((a,b) => {
    if (obj[b] == obj[a]) return a.localeCompare(b)
    return obj[b] - obj[a];
})

console.log(answer)
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare

Answer (score 1):

```js
const obj = { Peter: 3, Jeremy: 2, Chris: 1, Adam: 2 };

const result = Object.entries(obj) // get array of [key, value]
  // sort by value descending, then alphabetically by key
  .sort(([a,b],[c,d])=>d-b || a.localeCompare(c)) 
  .map(([i])=>i) // extract just the key

console.log(result)
```